# Three processes using Pipes is not running third process

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork, synchronous

I am working on a project for a computer architecture class, and I can't figure out why the third process in my C code is not running.
I was given a skeleton code by the TA, and I went to an extra session yesterday to figure out why I couldn't get it to work. It seems I'm not the only one. Some other students said that it was because the skeleton code was wrong, and the TA seemed to not be sure and said to just submit it if you think it's right.

I can get my code to print the correct results to the screen, but it won't save to a file and keeps getting stuck in the third process. The concept we are actually learning about is pipes and delays, so the focus is not necessarily on C, but rather on the pipes. I think I need to add sleep functions since there are multiple processes going on at once, but no matter what I do it keeps getting stuck.

My main questions are:
Is the skeleton code actually wrong, or am I just doing the rest of the assignment wrong?
Is it possible for me to fix the skeleton code so I can actually understand this concept? (I can't turn it in that way, but at least I'll know what's going on)

I will separate below which parts are skeleton code and note some of the things I've tried.

Skeleton code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define READ_END 0
#define WRITE_END 1
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
// declare pipes
    int fd1[2], fd2[2];
    pid_t pid;
    if (pipe(fd1) == -1 || pipe(fd2) == -1) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe failed");
        return 1;
    }
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
        return 1;
    }
    if (pid > 0) 
    { // Parent process
        close(fd1[READ_END]);
        close(fd2[WRITE_END]);
        FILE* fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

        //
        //FILE* fp2 = fopen("output.txt", "w");

        //

        if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file\n");
        exit(1);
        }
        char line[BUFSIZ];
        while (fgets(line, BUFSIZ, fp)) 
        {
            write(fd1[WRITE_END], line, strlen(line));
            memset(line, 0, BUFSIZ);
            read(fd2[READ_END], line, BUFSIZ);
            printf("%s", line);
            //fprintf(fp2, "%s", line); this isn't allowed
        }
        fclose(fp);
        //fclose(fp2);
        close(fd1[WRITE_END]);
        close(fd2[READ_END]);
    }
    else 
    { // Child process
        pid = fork();
        if (pid > 0) 
        { // Second process
            close(fd1[WRITE_END]);
            close(fd2[READ_END]);
            char line[BUFSIZ];
            while (read(fd1[READ_END], line, BUFSIZ)) 


//see note 1*

            {
                for (int i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++) {
                    // Change lower to upper and upper to lower cases
                    // write code here
                        if(isupper(line[i]))
                        {
                            line[i]=tolower(line[i]);
                        } else if(islower(line[i])) 
                        {
                            line[i]=toupper(line[i]);
                        }
                    }

//this is skeleton code

                write(fd2[WRITE_END], line, strlen(line));
                memset(line, 0, BUFSIZ);
            }
            close(fd1[READ_END]);
            close(fd2[WRITE_END]);
        }
        else 
        { // Third process


//see 2*

            // Close unused pipes
            //write code here
            close(fd1[READ_END]);
            close(fd2[WRITE_END]);
            close(fd1[WRITE_END]);

//The rest of the code is skeleton code, but I needed to change the code inside the while loop to write to output.txt. 

            FILE* fp = fopen("output.txt", "w");
            char line[BUFSIZ];


            //the code below is commented out because it keeps getting stuck in this loop
        
            /*
            while (read(fd2[READ_END], line, BUFSIZ)) 
            {
                // prints to the output.txt file
                // write code here
                fprintf(fp,"%s", line);

            }
            */ 

            fclose(fp);
            close(fd2[READ_END]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any advice anyone has on what's going on here would be appreciated.

1* The next part is where I had to write a process. This runs properly and will print to the screen. I have tried editing this to get the third process to run by adding sleep(2) at the beginning of the loop and sleep(3) at the end of the loop, and doing the inverse in the third process (so they total 5 seconds and each iteration won't start until after the previous one is complete) - I tried sleep(10) in the beginning of the third process only so the second process will always run first and complete before the third process starts. So far, sleep isn't working. I also tried wait(NULL) in various places; this also didn't work. - I have tried so many things I honestly cannot remember them all.

2* The next part I had to write myself and is where it keeps getting stuck. If i comment out the loop, the code will run completely. If I do not, the code gets stuck in the loop, but it doesn't run any code that is inside of it. I have tried writing print statements before the loop and in the loop. If it is before the loop, it will run once and the output is weird. Sometimes it runs the print line a few second after the code appears to be done running.
I tried printing to the screen the value of read(fd2[READ_END], line, BUFSIZ)) - sometimes it gives 0 and sometimes it gives a number - not sure why but thinking it has something to do with the time I run the code. I tried also printing BUFSIZ to the screen - the result didn't really make sense to me.

Comment: can you share your complete code, all in one block?

Comment: This is the entire code, but I can share it altogether.

Comment: it's updated with notes at the bottom

Comment: `while (read(fd1[READ_END], line, BUFSIZ))` is poor code. `read()` can return -1 which is an *error*, and the return value if positive indicates the number of bytes actually read. It is *impossible* to write correct `read()` code without storing the result into a variable. Say it was `while ((count = read(...)) > 0)`, the following write should be `write(fd2[WRITE_END], line, count)`, or in the case of the third process `fprintf(fp,"%.*s", count, line)` or `fwrite(fp, line, 1, count)`. This is your TA's fault for providing a bad `read()` example.

Comment: His code is also not transmitting the trailing null in the strings, while assuming it is present when read. NB Your sleeps are literally a waste of time. They are never necessary in network programming.

Comment: Ugh ok…. So I’d probably need to significantly modify skeleton code to get it working… thanks for your help… I will see what I can do

Comment: TA may claim that all those `memset()`s take care of the null termination, and they do, provided `strlen(line) < BUFSIZ`, which is nowhere checked: but, like the sleeps, `memset()` is never necessary in networking code. Show him these comments ...

Comment: He took away the third requirement, so my code is now working like it needs to for the assignment, but now I feel like I'm missing the concept. If all I need to do is write a loop to change the format of a sentence, then this becomes a ridiculously easy assignment that I mastered years ago.

Comment: I was able to get it working by creating a third fork to use for reading in the third process - it is used in the parent process so it wasn't letting me use it in the last process, I think